# Attach one Active Storage blob to multiple files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

In Rails, when attaching a file to an object, is there a way to check if it is already attached to another object? And if so, can I then use this existing attachment on a second file? The reasoning here is to prevent multiple uploads of the same files to the storage backend.

Specifically, this is stemming from files being attached in the development environment using `file_fixture_upload`.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach an existing blob to an object, just like the example: `person.avatar.attach(avatar_blob)` in the `#attach` rails doc: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Attached/One.html#method-i-attach .

But the key problem is "how to know the file is already uploaded and where is the corresponding blob?"

There are 2 possible ways to think about:

1. Try to find the blob by using the data stored in `active_storage_blobs` table.
2. Create another model to trace and maintain the file upload status.

### Sol 1: Try to find the blob by using the data stored in `active_storage_blobs` table.

The `active_storage_blobs` scheme is:

```
  create_table "active_storage_blobs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "key", null: false
    t.string "filename", null: false
    t.string "content_type"
    t.text "metadata"
    t.bigint "byte_size", null: false
    t.string "checksum"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: nil, null: false
    t.string "service_name"
    t.index ["key"], name: "index_active_storage_blobs_on_key", unique: true
  end
```

It is possible to find the blob by using the `filename` or `checksum`, but you need to implement the query on your own. There are some issues need to notice:

1. `filename` and `checksum` are not indexed by default and it may have efficiency issue when blob increases. You may consider indexing them if needed.
2. Need to know how the `filename` and `checksum` are generated in active storage and apply it on file when doing query.

### Sol 2: Create another model to trace and maintain the file upload status

The first solution is a little hack because the `active_storage_blobs` is supposed to be internal and we should not access them in rails app directly.

A better way is creating a model to trace and maintain the uploaded files and decide what information to store for querying a file. For example, we can create a `UploadedFile` model with a `checksum` field:

db schema

```
  create_table "uploaded_files", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "checksum", null: false
    t.index ["checksum"], name: "index_uploaded_files_on_checksum", unique: true
  end
```

And implement related methods to handle the upload as below:

app/models/uploaded_file.rb

```
class UploadedFile < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached(:uploaded_file)

  class << self
    def find_or_create_file_blob(file)
      blob = find_blob_by_given_file(file)
      if blob.blank?
        blob = create_uploaded_file_and_do_upload(file)
      end
      blob
    end

    private

    def find_blob_by_given_file(file)
      checksum = calculate_checksum(file)
      existing_uf = UploadedFile.where(checksum:).take
      existing_uf.present? ? existing_uf.uploaded_file.blob : nil
    end

    def create_uploaded_file_and_do_upload(file)
      checksum = calculate_checksum(file)
      uf = UploadedFile.create(checksum:)
      uf.uploaded_file.attach(file)
      if uf.uploaded_file.attched?
        return uf.uploaded_file.blob
      else
        # do error handling when upload failed
      end
    end

    def calculate_checksum(file)
      # implement how to calculate checksum with a given file
    end
  end
  # ...
end
```

Finally, when upload a file to `persion.avatar`, instead of updating `persion.avatar` directly, use `UploadedFile.find_or_create_file_blob` to find the blob first then attach it to `persion.avatar`.

```
blob = UploadedFile.find_or_create_file_blob(params[:file])
persion.avatar.attach(blob)
```